# continuous joint distribution with bounds for a variable dependent on another variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X$ and $Y$ are R.V's with joint distribution $\frac{8xy}{3}$  where $0<x<1$ and $x<y<2x$. find their covariance. I know the process you take is to get both marginal distributions for $X$ and $Y$ then get the expected values of these and then the expected value of the joint distribution but my question is when obtaining the marginals or expected values do you use $x<y<2x$ throughout when integrating over $Y$ or can/should you use $0<y<2$?

Answer (score 0):

Sketch the support. It is a triangle; which is also a union of triangles.

$\quad\begin{align}\{(x,y): 0<x<1, x<y<2x\}&=\triangle(0,0)(1,1)(1,2)\\&=\triangle(0,0)(1,1)(1/2,1)\cup\triangle(1/2,1)(1,1)(1,2)\\&=\{(x,y): 0<y<2, y/2<x<\min\{y,1\}\}\end{align}$

So, the marginal pdf for $Y$ shall be a piecewise function over the parts $0<y<1$ and $1\leq y<2$ (and equaling $0$ elsewhere):

$\qquad\begin{align}f_X(x)&=\mathbf 1_{0\lt x\lt 1}\int_x^{2x} 8xy/3\,\mathrm d y\\f_Y(y) &=\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt 1}\int_{y/2}^y 8xy/3\,\mathrm d x+\mathbf 1_{1\leq y\lt 2}\int_{y/2}^1 8xy/3\,\mathrm d x\end{align}$

Comment: ah, thank you I see that from the sketch, but for the expected value do you use 0<y<2 and 0<x<1? why or why not?

Comment: @JohnvanZalk , you use whichever you find easiest. $\quad\begin{align}\mathsf E(X) &= \int_0^1 \int_x^{2x} 8x^2y/3\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\&=\int_0^1\int_{y/2}^y 8x^2y/3\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y+\int_1^2\int_{y/2}^1 8x^2y/3\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\end{align}$